# Executing a PHP query and flowing the result into a grid container from left to right

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to flow the result set of a PHP Query into a grid. I centered the content, but I would like to have the content flow from left to right and I'm stuck with the center, start, or end position.

I only have one grid-item that I'm looping through and then inserting the result set into a grid.

The end result so far is that all the results line-up in the center of the page. I want them to flow from left to right.

I would like to modify the .grid-item and float it from left to right without using a float element because the float has no effect on the display: grid.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            *, *:before, *:after{
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body{
                margin: 0;
            }
            .wrapper{
                display: grid;
                width: 100%;
                height:  auto;
                margin:  0 auto;
                background: lightblue;
            }
.grid-container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns:  auto auto auto auto;
            grid-template-rows:  auto auto auto auto;
            column-gap: 5px;
            row-gap: 5px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: flex-start;
            }
        .grid-item{ 
            display: inline-grid;
            font-family:  helvetica, sans-serif;
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: pink;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            align-items: flex-start;
            align-content: flex-start;
            }
    /*.grid-item:hover{ 
                display: grid;
                font-family:  helvetica, sans-serif;
                width: 200px;
                height: 300px;
                text-align: right;
                font-weight: bold;
                background: tomato;
                cursor: pointer;
                color:  gold;
                }
            b.b{
                color:  white;
            }
        </style>
        <header>
        </header>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <?php
    DEFINE ("DB_USER", "root");
    DEFINE ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    DEFINE ("DB_PASSWORD", "myroot");
    DEFINE ("DB_NAME", "corporate");
    
    $dbc = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    
    mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
    
    $q = "SELECT sku, name, price FROM products";
    
    $r = $dbc->query($q, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
    
    while(list($sku, $name, $price) = $r->fetch_row())
    printf("<div class='wrapper'>
                <div class='grid-container'>
                    <div class='grid-item'>(%s)<b class='b'>%s:</b>
                    \$%d </div>
                </div>
            </div>", $sku, $name, $price);
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your html does not seems valid to me, you are printing tags after the end tag <html/>

Comment: It's a combination of php and html. I added the html element because I wanted to add styles to my html in the php section.

Comment: Yes but you should generate valid html to begin with, so move </body> and </html> after the php

Comment: I brought down the </body> and </html> tags. It didn't help? I'm still stuck.

Comment: I would remove .wrapper and .grid-container from the printf and only keep the item

Comment: Thanks Lk77. I removed the wrapper and grid-container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your items to flow from left to right you need to only have one wrapper/container element for all your items :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        *, *:before, *:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .wrapper {
            display: grid;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: lightblue;
        }

        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns:  auto auto auto auto;
            grid-template-rows:  auto auto auto auto;
            column-gap: 5px;
            row-gap: 5px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: flex-start;
        }

        .grid-item {
            display: inline-grid;
            font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
            text-align: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: pink;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            align-items: flex-start;
            align-content: flex-start;
        }

        /*.grid-item:hover{
                    display: grid;
                    font-family:  helvetica, sans-serif;
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 300px;
                    text-align: right;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    background: tomato;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    color:  gold;
                    }
                b.b{
                    color:  white;
                }*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <div class='grid-container'>
            <?php
            DEFINE("DB_USER", "root");
            DEFINE("DB_HOST", "localhost");
            DEFINE("DB_PASSWORD", "myroot");
            DEFINE("DB_NAME", "corporate");
    
            $dbc = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    
            mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
    
            $q = "SELECT sku, name, price FROM products";
    
            $r = $dbc->query($q, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
    
            while (list($sku, $name, $price) = $r->fetch_row())
            {
                printf("<div class='grid-item'>(%s)<b class='b'>%s:</b>
                        \$%d </div>", $sku, $name, $price);
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it will create a grid with 4 items per row